# Adding more than one property to a promise

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a function in my web app where I can add data to a promise. However so far I can only be able to add one property via the parameters in my methods.
The code is executed on a button click which calls the add function.
This then calls the template service function `create(name, name2)`.

**createsharecase.component.ts**

```
// Function to add a case
add(name: string, name2: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    name2 = name2.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.templateService.create(name, name2).then(cases =>
    { this.cases.push(cases); })
    console.log("Name1: " + name + " Name 2: " + name2)}


// Create a template
create(name: string, name2: string): Promise<ICase> {
console.log("Template service method: " + name2);
return this._http
  .post(this._caseUrl, JSON.stringify
  ({ name: name, name2: name2 }), { headers: this.headers })
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => res.json().data as ICase)
  .catch(this.handleError)};
```

This is the output of my code:

[image: Browser Image of output]

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve a promise with an object or an array. I belive there is no multiargumental Promise.

Resolving with an object:

```
new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  // ... something fancy
  resolve({
    data: {
      // your args goes there
    }
    err: {
    }
  });
  // ... if error
  reject({
    data: {
    }
    err: {
      // errors
    }
  })
});
```

Resolving with an array is rather very close to object resolving:

```
new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  // ... something fancy
  resolve({
    data: [
    // your cases go there
    ]
    err: {
    }
  });
  // ... if error
  reject({
    data: {
    }
    err: {
      // errors
    }
  })
});
```

Very handy there is [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Destructuring_assignment):

```
// While the object is passed to then:
const { data: { value1, value2 } } = resolveValue;
const { value1, value2 } = resolveValue.data;

// While the array is passed:
const [ case1, case2 ] = resolveValue.data;
```

[Promise documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)